# How do i create an htaccess rule when none of the other rules are met and how to capture that rule in php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have multiple url's like so

```
http://www.example/discography/
http://www.example/discography/country/1/canada
http://www.example/discography/format/1/cd
http://www.example/discography/year/2010
```

I've created htaccess rules for each like so

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php

RewriteRule ^discography/?$ music/music.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^discography/country/(\d+)(?:/[^/]+)?/?$ music/music.php?country=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^discography/format/(\d+)(?:/[^/]+)?/?$ music/music.php?format=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^discography/year/([0-9]{4}+)/?$ music/music.php?year=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So far, so good.

On my php script, i'm capturing the values like so

```
if ( isset($_GET['country']) && is_numeric($_GET['country']) ) {
    echo 'country id';
    $get_countryid = (int)$_GET['country'];

} elseif ( isset($_GET['format']) && is_numeric($_GET['format']) ) {
    echo 'format id';
    $get_formatid = (int)$_GET['format'];

} elseif ( isset($_GET['year']) && is_numeric($_GET['year']) ) {
    echo 'year';
    $get_year = (int)$_GET['year'];

} else {
    // default value for url http://www.example.com/discography
    if ( empty($_GET) ) {
        echo 'http://www.example.com/discography';
    } else {
        echo 'None of the rules are met... show a msg';
    }
}
```

Here's where i'm running into trouble...

If the user enters, for example, an erroneous url like this one

```
http://www.example/discography/@#$GRTGRWH$TG%G
```

Even if the url is an invalid one, I don't want to lose the user. I want the user to still see the page so he sees other options to click on.

I've tried stuff like this with no success

```
RewriteRule ^discography/(.*)/?$ music/music.php [L]
```

How do i create an htaccess rule when none of the other rules are met and how to capture that rule in php?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your problem? and what happens if you type the wrong url?

Comment: @starkeen if i type `http://www.example/discography/` i get echo `http://www.example.com/discography`. But if i type `http://www.example/discography/@#$GRTGRWH$TG%G` i also get echo `http://www.example.com/discography` but I want to get echo  `None of the rules are met... show a msg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting unexpected  results for the following  reasons :

Your Rules

```
 RewriteRule ^discography/?$ music/music.php [L,QSA]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^discography/(.*)/?$ music/music.php [L]
```

both are pointing  to the same path `/music/music.php`  with empty `$_GET` variable.
So your `if ( empty($_GET) ) {
        echo 'http://www.example.com/discography' ;}` statement is running for both urls.

You can fix this by replacing your `(empty($_GET))` with `($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]=="/discography"))` This will  check if the current uri is `/discography` .

or you can add a GET perameter to the destination url of your second rule to solve this

```
 RewriteRule ^discography/(.*)/?$ music/music.php?foo=bar [L]
```